# Facebook 3.0: Things I don't understand when authenticating a user on android

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, authorization

I find something strange with facebook 3.0.

Without the facebook application installed on android, i can use openForPublish and it will asked me for basic permission then publish stream permission. If using openForRead then using newPermissionsRequest for publish stream permission in the callback function, I will end up logging in twice.

With the facebook application installed on the other hand, I cannot use openForPublish during the installation time coz it required Read Permission. If using openForRead, then use newPermissionsRequest for publish stream, I will able request the publish stream but the callback i passed into newPermissionsRequest wouldn't get called.

Does anyone having the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The correct sequence of events is to first call openToRead, then requestNewPublishPermissions. This fits in well with the current model of permissions requests.

For the web dialog case, please upgrade to 3.0.1, it addresses the multiple login issue.